# useMemo function running during rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Basically what I'm trying to do is call this `'myMemoFunction'` function in a part of my code. The problem is that from what I've read in the documentation, `useMemo()` executes this function right on rendering, therefore the `myArray` parameter is still empty. Then it returns the error below.

```
const myMemoFunction = useMemo((myArray) => {
    const users = myArray.map((a) => a.user)
    return users;
})
```

Error:

> myArray is undefined

Answer (score 1):

You should use `useCallback` in that case
as `useMemo` memoizes a variable. Also I doubt it can take arguments.

Edit:

```js
const myMemoFunction = useCallback((myArray) => {
    // this won't be called on renders
    const users = myArray.map((a) => a.user)
    return users;
}, [] /* dont forget the dependency you want to evaluate only once */)

// later
myMemoFunction(arr);
```

Edit 2 with useMemo:

```js
const myMemoVariable = useMemo(() => {
    // re-evaluates each time myArray changes
    const users = myArray.map((a) => a.user)
    return users;
}, [myArray])

// note that we dont use myMemoVariable() to get our variable
console.log(myMemoVariable)
```

Comment: But will useCallBack give me the same functionality as useMemo? of memorizing values

Comment: Yes but you can call it as a function later: ```myMemoFunction(arr)``` and its not called at the render, like regular functions.

Comment: const callFunc = useCallback((registers) => {
    myMemoFunction(registers)
  })  I basically did this but it didn't work, returns the same error

Comment: ```myMemoFunction``` can't take arguments if uses ```useMemo```. I added example in the response.

Comment: So does that mean if I call the myMemoFunction() function multiple times with the same argument it won't need to reprocess?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by reprocess, but it will be ```re-evaluated``` depending of the dependency injection you defined. As the doc says, it's usefull if you want to keep the same reference between renders. Having said that, it will always run what's inside even if you call multiple time with the same arguments.

Comment: Updated the answer with useMemo

Answer (score 0):

update your code to this

```
const myMemoFunction = useMemo((myArray) => {

// myArray could be undefined, that was why ? was added

    const users = myArray?.map((a) => a.user)

    return users;

}, [myArray]) // myArray is in a dependency of the function
```

your memo function will get updated with the new *myArray* variable

it is always good to initialize your myArray variable as an array e.g []